# Stylesheet web resource not being deployed by CRM Developer Toolkit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, dynamics-crm-2011

I've created a "dummy" unmanaged solution to try out CRM Developer Toolkit (in its latest stable version available today), everything seems to work properly *except* CSS files.

In my Toolkit solution, `Plugins` and `Workflow` projects are empty (I just created the SNK for the Plugins project), and a Silverlight Application project has been added.

I added to the `CrmPackage` project three web resources:

- a JScript file `test.js` (empty)
- a HTM file `test.htm` (contains a dummy html skeleton)
- a CSS file `test.css` (filled with a couple of attributes just to not leave it empty)

When I right-click -> *Deploy* the `CrmPackage` project, inside the solution I get this:

- a XAP (from the Silverlight project)
- 2xDLLs (from `Plugins` and `Worflow` projects)
- the HTM and JS web resources
- ***the CSS file is nowhere to be found***

I receive no errors whatsoever from the Visual Studio IDE (or from the CRM), and I was expecting the CSS file to show up amongst the other web resources...

... What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you provide the link to CRM Developer Toolkit (in its latest stable version available today)?

Comment: @keerz The Developer toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 was released as part of UR5 SDK release and is available for download here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004 (latest release: 2012-03-22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a very trivial issue: having given the same name to my resources, they obviously failed to publish (they would have ended up having the same name as web resources!)

I returned on this issue, opened a new project, went with a different naming like this:

- JScript file became `myScript.js`
- HTM file became `myPage.htm`
- CSS file became `myStyle.css`

And the project deployed perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

[I typically create my WebResources in the CRM Solution](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/220/Managing-Web-Resources-and-Plug-ins-with-the-CRM-Developer-Toolkit.aspx) and then use "Add to Packaging Project" from the CRM Browser (I don't like the naming that results from the toolkit).  I would try creating the .CSS in the CRM Solution, adding it to your Visual Studio, and then deploying a change.